# libvlcsharp - iOS transcode not accepting media option parameters

Tags: xamarin.ios, libvlc, libvlcsharp, vlckit

I've been using the Xamarin libVLCSharp player for a while on iOS and Android and it works well. I've added a transcoding feature, but for some reason my libVLCSharp code works fine to transcode on Android (change codec, bitrate, fps), but the same transcode media options on iOS (iPhone 12 pro, iOS 14.4.2) produce no changes in the output video file compared to the input video file. I have attached the sample video file which I am attempting to transcode.

Here is my C# code (which contains the transcode media options that works on Android, but not iOS):

```cs
    Core.Initialize();

    _vlc = new LibVLC();

    _player = new LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer(_vlc);

    _media = new Media(_vlc, _source, FromType.FromPath);

    _media.AddOption ($":sout=#transcode{{vcodec=h264,vb=700000,acodec=aac,ab=96,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}}:std{{access=file,mux=ts,dst={destination}}}");

    var result = _player.Play(_media);
```

Any help or pointers on why this transcoding command is not producing any change in the output media file compared to the original would be greatly appreciated!

iOS Logfile
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C0UGzE7hqCJYozTvubyK1BKWcZvG18VY/view

Sample file I'm using to test transcoding:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MvJKJnu2ii6XMANuWRkHLqmu78e9x03q/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$":sout=#transcode{venc={module=avcodec{codec=h264_videotoolbox}, vcodec=h264},venc={module=vpx{quality-mode=2},vcodec=VP80},samplerate=44100,soverlay}:file{dst={destination},mux=ts}"
```

Feel free to remove unnecessary options, but from my findings this exact string should work.

Comment: Thanks - this worked! Seems like iOS is picky when it comes to transcode parameters.